# Scala return Object type for Map method

Tags: scala

I have a function called as "readStock" which should return value of type [String,WeatherReading] whereas "WeatherReading" is object for the case class "WeatherReadingStub". I don't know how to declare and return object for the function "readStock".

Code:-

```
package HW9

object WeatherStub {
    //Setting file name
    val fileName = "weather.csv"
    //Calling Main
    def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
        val weatherData: Map[String, WeatherReading] = readWeather(fileName)
            printWeather(weatherData)
        }
        def readWeather(fn: String): Map[String,WeatherReading] = {
            //Creating a mutable map to collect all the values
            val weatherMuteMap = scala.collection.mutable.Map[String, WeatherReading]()
            //Checking for empty or null values
            def IsEmptyOrNull(s: String): Option[Float] = {
                if ((s ne null) && s.trim.length > 0) Some(s.toFloat) else None
            }
            //Reading file 
            for (line <- io.Source.fromFile(fn).getLines()) {
                val list1 = line.split(",", -1).map(_.trim).toList
            //Setting up default values
            val TotalPrecp: Option[Float] = IsEmptyOrNull(list1(1).toString) match { case Some(i) => Some(i) case _ => None}
            val LowPrecp: Option[Float] = IsEmptyOrNull(list1(2).toString) match { case Some(i) => Some(i) case _ => None}
            val HighPrecp: Option[Float] = IsEmptyOrNull(list1(3).toString) match { case Some(i) => Some(i) case _ => None}

            //Creating object for the case class WeatherReadingStub
            val WeatherReading = WeatherReadingStub(TotalPrecp,LowPrecp,HighPrecp)

            //Adding elements to the mutable list
            weatherMuteMap(list1(0).toString) = WeatherReading.toString
        }
        //Converting to Immutbale Map
        weatherMuteMap.toMap
    }


    def printWeather(weatherMap: Map[String, String]): Unit = {
        //Format of the message to be printed
        println("(Date,{Precipitation,LowTemperature,HighTemperature})\tAverageTemperature")

        //Printing the average temp values calculated in Case Class using object
        weatherMap.toSeq.sortBy(_._1).foreach(wd => println(wd + "\t" + wd._2.averageTemperature.getOrElse("N/A")))
        println

    }

}
```

Case Class Code:-

```
package HW9

case class WeatherReadingStub(precipitation: Option[Float], lowTemperature: Option[Float], highTemperature: Option[Float]) {

    def averageTemperature: Option[Float] = (lowTemperature, highTemperature) match {case (Some(i),Some(j)) =>  Some((i + j)/2) case _ => None}

    override def toString: String = s"{${precipitation.getOrElse("MISSING")},${lowTemperature.getOrElse("MISSING")},${highTemperature.getOrElse("MISSING")}}"
}
```

Comment: By `value of type [String,WeatherReading]` you mean a tuple?

Comment: By "WeatherReading is object for the case class WeatherReadingStub" do you mean the companion object? Companion objects have the same name as the class and a `case class` automatically creates its own companion object.

Comment: You'll get better and faster answers to your questions if you follow [these helpful guidelines](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). It would also be helpful if you format your code so that we don't have to scroll left-and-right to read it.

Comment: Sorry about it i will make sure format it going forward. Yes it should be a tuple. In the print method i am printing the object "wd"                  
 def printWeather(weatherMap: Map[String, WeatherReading]): Unit = {
        //Format of the message to be printed
        println("(Date,{Precipitation,LowTemperature,HighTemperature})\tAverageTemperature")

        //Printing the average temp values calculated in Case Class using object
        weatherMap.toSeq.sortBy(_._1).foreach(wd => println(wd + "\t" + wd._2.averageTemperature.getOrElse("N/A")))
        println

    }

Comment: What @jwvh meant was that you need to provide us with a minimal, complete and verifiable example. Even if the code you posted was completely self-sufficient and instantly compilable (which it's not), there's much more of it than is actually needed to demonstrate the problem itself. If you reduce all this code to 5-6 lines where you just create a simple map and get a wrong type (without all this weather stuff that is unrelated to the core of the problem, not to mention reading from a file etc) you will not only get an answer quickly, but probably even solve it yourself at that point.

Answer (score 0):

check your class name WeatherReadingStub. In Object WeatherStub, the
readWeather method builds a mutable Map with key the date (type String) and value is a WeatherReading object. Your class WeatherReadingStub has averageTemperature and you have refer WeatherReadingStub in your MAP[String , WeatherReadingStub]. If you replace WeatherReading with your defined object WeatherReadingStub, This program will run. 
Your definition of MAP should be 
val weatherData: Map[String, WeatherReadingStub] = readWeather(fileName) (replace all other occurrences.)